# How to graft with tortoisehg

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I heard of the new hg [graft](http://selenic.com/hg/help/graft) feature, it's a useful feature to apply certain changesets from a branch to another.

Is it possible to use it from tortoisehg?

Comment: I don't think tortoisehg supports graft. Not all command line options are supported in tortoisehg.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

TortoiseHG 2.8

[image: Graft]

Selected changeset (r64) will be grafted to local (active) branch "default", because Working Dir parent is r66

Comment: Is it possible to do this from an external repository?

Comment: @greydet - I don't know, that is "external repository". Anyway, all Mecurial command always applied to local repository (it's DVCS after all)

Comment: I mean: is it possible to "graft" a changeset from another repository in the current repository using tortoiseHg? I other word an equivalent to the command: hg graft -R /path/to/repo <changeset>

Comment: @greydet - graft, by design *"copy changes from other branches onto the current branch"*, thus - no, it's operation inside single repo

Comment: you are right! In fact I need to use the TransplantExtension to cherrypick a changeset from another repository...

Comment: @greydet - No!!! "The graft command provides similar functionality in Mercurial 2.0 or newer and has smarter merge capability" - from Transplant wiki. If repositories are unrelated, you can graft bundle, if related - pull source to target before grafting

Comment: it would be nice to expand the answer to include an example of grafting from a different repository. I'm not sure what to make of _"If repositories are unrelated, you can graft bundle, if related - pull source to target before grafting"_