# Merge only some files/changesets between branches with Mercurial

Tags: version-control, mercurial, branching-and-merging, tortoisehg

**Note:** a similar question, [Mercurial: Merging one file between branches in one repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078881/mercurial-merging-one-file-between-branches-in-one-repo), asks specifically about merging "only certain files, instead of whole changeset?" Contrary to that, I would be OK with merging certain changesets, not single files from a changeset.

---

I've got a VCS-related question for which I cannot find an answer (perhaps not googling the correct words). Maybe the whole idea is flawed. Please let me know.

Suppose in my version control repository I have two branches, **default** and **feature**. While working on the feature, I wrote a nice function `foo.py`. We decided to abandon the whole feature development, so the **feature** branch is going to be closed without merging into **default**. The files from **feature** should not appear in **default**, with one exception—we do want to keep the nice `foo.py` function, so it should appear in **default**.

Is it possible, without manipulating files off-VCS (which would cause history loss)? For example, could I somehow only merge the changesets where `foo.py` was created/modified?

A (realistic) variant of this situation is that `foo.py` was originally taken into **feature** from **default**. While working in **feature**, I modify `foo.py`. Now I want to abandon **feature** but have the modified `foo.py` in **default**.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mercurial: Merging one file between branches in one repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078881/mercurial-merging-one-file-between-branches-in-one-repo)

Comment: @DaveInCaz, the difference is that I don't want to split a changeset. I would be OK with taking whole changesets.

Comment: graft the single changeset?

Comment: @Tom I've never used graft. Will check it today!

Comment: @Tom, that was it! Can you please add it as a short answer? I think it's useful for others, to find the graft extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single changeset can be [grafted](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/help/graft) onto another branch.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16900361/361714) shows how to graft using thg.